# Copying spreadsheets to a new file without the macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have written this code to copy some of my spreadsheets to a new file, but all the macros from the original file go to the new file as links to the original file. I would like to copy the the spreadsheets and have the macros removed in the new file. Please find below my code, how could I change it?

```
Sub IndRepPD()
    Dim NewName As String
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to generate an Indidual Report for PD?" & vbCr & _
    "The file will be saved as PD_VA2013_KPI in the same directory as the original." _
    , vbYesNo, "Generate Individual Report for PD") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False

         On Error GoTo ErrCatcher
        Sheets(Array("Inhalt", "PD", "PD Quality", "Glossary", "Status", "PD History")).Copy
        On Error GoTo 0

            For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.Cells.Copy
            ws.[A1].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Cells(1, 1).Select
            ws.Activate
        Next ws
        Cells(1, 1).Select

            For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
            nm.Delete
        Next nm
        ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
        Worksheets("PD").Select
            NewName = "PD_VA2013_KPI"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & NewName & ".xls"
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    Exit Sub

ErrCatcher:
    MsgBox "Specified sheets do not exist within this workbook"
End Sub
```

Comment: Which Excel version are you using? If you are using >=xl2007 then simply save the file as an `.xlsx` :)

Comment: If in a version prior to XL 2007, are the macros in the Code modules of the worksheets? If they are, then you either have to copy the contents of the worksheets in order to get the data without the code, or use [VBA Extensibility / Chip Pearson, VBA Legend & all round XL Guru](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) to remove the code programmatically after the copy

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am using 2010.

Comment: Perfect :) See my first comment

Comment: @SiddharthRout I tried saving as .xlsx and the macros are still there...

Comment: Not possible :) An `.xlsx` file cannot store macros. May I see the code?

Comment: @user2220264 what are the macros, what are they doing?

Comment: They are simple macros to edit some specific type of text. What is happening is that once I use this macro in the new document, the old document opens and the changes are made in the old document. So the code above is creating hyperlinks for the macros from the original document. I tried ws.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete but there was no changes.

Comment: @SiddharthRout can you think of anything I could do to deactivate the macros in the new file?

Comment: How many such buttons are there?

Comment: 3 buttons in each of the 25 new files that are generated with this macro.

Answer (score 0):

The .xlsx doesn't store the macros, but links to the macros of the original file still exist if you run your macros with buttons in the spreadsheets.

Comment: That´s right! I have buttons for the macros and the hyperlinks run the macros in the original document, instead of running it in the new one.

Comment: so remove the hyperlinks or buttons ... alternatively, modify the buttons to execute code in the current workbook

Comment: I tried ws.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete but there were no changes. My codes generate 25 different files and I dont wan't to modify or remove them manually.